# Azure.Documents.Document - Method not found

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

The error I got when I run below code

> Method not found:
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ResourceResponse`1>
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IDocumentClient.ReadDocumentAsync(System.String,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions)'.

Before this I was able to run the code with

> **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage**, **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table** trying to migrate to **Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table;**, **Microsoft.Azure.Storage**

this is my code, I believe is nothing to do with code, but not sure how to fix this, and I've downgrade the **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common** to version 9.0.0.1-preview according to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/712)

```
public static async Task<CloudTable> CreateTableAsync(string tableName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
    try
    {
        await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    }
    catch (StorageException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    return table;
}

public static CloudStorageAccount CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(string storageConnectionString)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    try
    {
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
    }
    catch (FormatException fex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fex);
        throw;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException aux)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return storageAccount;
}
```

Appreciate if anyone could advise. Thanks

Comment: Sorry,I can't get your theme. You mean you used `Azure.Storage` package,it worked fine. And now you migrate to `Azure.Cosmos.Table1` package, it crashed? But I can't see `ReadDocumentAsync` method in your sample code.

Comment: ya. i don't get it too. i not sure why, it crashed at this line CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);